# JUnit tests's analytic tool?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, automation, reporting

I'm asking this question after a long fruitless research...

In our automation team we are using *JUnit* to run about 1000 different tests. Today, if we have any failures, we check and analyze them through *Jenkins* 'test reports' plugin.

My manager asked me to learn and research about 'smarter' analytical ways, in which we could use to understand better the tests behavior over time.

The goal is to manage and arrange the data in a report in convenient way and also have the capabilities to apply different analytics rules on the data (e.g. to be able to see a specific test's segmentation overtime).

My questions is - is there any tool or capability of doing such a thing?